# Acquire viewModelScope in helper class used in ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, coroutinescope

Hi I have a question: what would be the best practice to pass viewModelScope to the helper/manager class used in viewModel.

For example, I would like to create an AccountManager class that would take care of the account, perform some async task operations, read/write from the database etc...
I want to expose the result through Kotlin Flow and collect it in my ViewModel, and for that reason I need to access viewModelScope (so I can emit values), because creating a new scope doesn't seem like a very good idea.

I'm using Hilt dependency injection, and I would like to inject account manager as a dependency in ViewModel.
Also, one thing worth mentioning is that I would like to use this Account Manager in more than one place in my app, because it's encapsulating some repetitive operations.
There is a concern that if I create AccountManager as a Singleton I could create memory leak if I pass a particular viewModelScope to it...
So basically I need your opinion what would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that the `emit` and `collect` are called in the **same** `CoroutineScope`. Please look at the source code. It is not necessary to transfer the scope to anywhere explicitly

```
public suspend inline fun <T> Flow<T>.collect(crossinline action: suspend (value: T) -> Unit): Unit =
    collect(object : FlowCollector<T> {
        override suspend fun emit(value: T) = action(value)
    })
```

The `collect` method is `suspend`. Internally, it runs both the **flow block** and the **collect block**. Therefore, all the work of sending and receiving data will be done in the coroutine, in which we call the `collect()` method.

```
class TestViewModel(private val manager: Manager) : ViewModel() {

    private fun load() =
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            manager.doWork1().collect {

            }
        }

    private fun load2() =
        viewModelScope.launch {
            manager.doWork2().collect {
            }
        }
}
```

Manager class

```
class Manager {

    fun doWork1() = flow {
        for (k in 1..10) {
            val t = newValue(k)
            emit(t)
        }
    }

    suspend fun doWork2() = flow {
        withContext(IO) {
            for (k in 1..10) {
                val t = newValue(k)
                emit(t)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun newValue(param: Int) {
        delay(5000)
        Random(param).nextInt()
    }
}
```

Comment: My manager uses api which has its own internal callbacks. So I would like to use coroutine Channel, and do something like: `val flow = channel.receiveAsFlow()`
And coroutine channel would be able to accept sealed class' parameter, and send it.  `channel.send(ManagerClassEvent())`
Now, to send event with channel, I need coroutine scope.
I've tried using LiveData and then convert it to flow, but it only uses conflated flow, so it might happen that I lose some data...
How good/bad solution would be to add method in manager that would pass scope to it: `fun setScope(scope : CoroutineScope)` ?

Comment: I think you can just mark your methods as *suspend* where you need to call **channel.send(ManagerClassEvent())**, don't need to share **CoroutineScope** when